# Referencing resource files from a razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, internationalization

I use ASP.NET Internationalization from Code52 at http://code52.org/aspnet-internationalization/ which uses (language) resource files.

From my controller I reference the string I want like this

```
ViewBag.Message = Language.Index_Title;
```

Is it possible to reference the values directly in the (razor) view?
Something like this: `@Resources.Language.Index_Title;`

Comment: All problems were solved when I changed the resource file properties to:  

Build Action: Embedded resource
Copy to output directory: do not copy

Comment: I found that the view will not reflect changes immediately.  After you change/rename/move the resource files, close and reopen the view.

Answer (score 11):

In your web.config you have the "Pages" section... there you need to add your Resource namespace... that way you don't need to declare it in every page using "using".

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
    <add namespace="Your.Resources.Namespace" />  <!--ADD THIS LINE-->
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Then, assuming your resource file is called "Language", in your Razor view you use:

```
@Language.Index_Title
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work for me, but the intellisense indicates that it's all right...

Comment: @ChristerKolterjahn, this is the tutorial I followed when I did this in my project: http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-part-2.aspx

Comment: I believe this needs to be added to the views web.config, rather than root web.config

Comment: @CodeWorks... good point... I suppose I have it in both places.

Comment: All problems were solved when I changed the resource file properties to: Build Action: Embedded resource Copy to output directory: do not copy

Comment: @ChristerKolterjahn, ahhh you have your resources embedded in your MVC project! I thought you had a separate project for your resource files!

Comment: You will also probably need to set your access modifier to `Public` in the resource editor for this to be accessible to Razor

Answer (score 5):

Modify your Resource file in properties in Custom Tool you have to add the value "**PublicResXFileCodeGenerator**" as well as in your view you can use the resource file.

Answer (score 3):

Try @ViewContext.HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(classKey, resourceKey) . Hope this helps